# ignoring an Ajax fail when returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure how to title this, hopefully it's not too confusing. I have a piece of js code which performs a piped operation on a list of objects. It must perform a series of ajax requests in sequence, and return a result. Here's some very simplified code

```
var urls = [ 
    { url: "http://myurl.com/1", expected: "one" }, 
    { url: "http://myurl.com/2", expected: "two" }
];

$(document).on("click", "#runselftest", function () {
    for (var u in urls) {
        values.push(u);
        dfdNext = dfdNext.pipe(function () {
            return testUrl(values.shift());
        });
    }
    dfd.resolve();
});

testUrl = function (i) {                   
    return $.ajax({
        url: urls[i].url,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result.result == urls[i].expected) {
            // yay
        }
        else {
            // aww
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        // this is causing the problem
    });
};
```

I want my op to continue processing even on a fail condition in ajax. However, if I `return $.ajax` and the first operation fails, the pipe stops. if I *don't* `return $.ajax`, but instead return a deferred promise in `.always`, the ops happen asynchronously. I want them to happen *synchronously* - in order. The second op must wait for the first to complete before it runs.

Do I need to rewrite my code or is there a simple solution?

Comment: I think if you use `.then` instead of `.pipe` it will always return a `Deferred` object instead of a `Promise`. That might work.

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv: `then` is only useful if you provide both a success and fail callback to it, otherwise it is the same as `done`, which does not help in this case.

Comment: Now I understand your issues, I've updated answer to meet your requirements (with minimal code changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better use a wrapper deferred object

```
testUrl = function (i) { 
    var d = $.Deferred();                  
    $.ajax({
        url: urls[i].url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            d.resolve();
        },
        error: function(){
            d.reject();
        }
    });

    return d.promise();
};
```

you  can use it like this

```
var deferred = test();
deferred.always(function(){
    //you can pout your coce
});
```

Comment: This actually solves the problem, if I change `d.reject()` to `d.resolve()`. What I specifically want to do is resolve the promise _even on fail_, so in this case this pattern is necessary. I can't see a way to do it without this pattern since I want to override what `.fail` returns

Comment: Yes returning a deferred object will give more control over it as its upto the developer when he wants to resolve/reject the promise.

Comment: @roryok: Yes, if you force errors to return a success you avoid the problem. That was of course not what was intended here, but your change will make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise1 = return $.ajax();
var promise2 = return $.ajax();

$.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(p1, p2) {
    //this will pipe them in order. If one fails it should move to the next, you just won't get any data from the failed promise
});
```

Comment: This is in parallel. The OP wanted synchronously.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It is a promise, it is going to be parallel. He wants them synchronously only in the idea of wanting them to return in order.

Comment: Yes... and `$.when` will run them in parallel. The OP states "I want them to happen synchronously - in order. The second op must wait for the first to complete before it runs."

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. A $.when is similar to a WaitAll in C#. When all of the promises have returned in "any order" then the done function will fire off. Inside of that done function are params for the completed tasks (p1, p2 in this example). In that function use p1 before p2 (sync from  parallel tasks).

Comment: I use these all the time. `$.when` starts all operations *at the same time* and moves on when all are complete. The OP appears to state they want the operations sequentially. "I want them to happen synchronously - in order." Perhaps I am misunderstanding his English?

Comment: No, @TrueBlueAussie, you understood me perfectly. They must happen one at a time, in order. Starting them all at the same time is not acceptable.

Comment: @roryok They are promises (async operations). You can't guarantee the tasks will finish in order but you can guarantee that you use the finished tasks in order (which is what you wanted).

Comment: With `then()` you *can* wait and run them sequentially. Also `then()` can be chained with other `then()` results in a loop. You *are* "correct", just not for the question asked :)

Comment: Fair enough :). If that's what he is wanting then why use promises at all. Just wrap the $.ajax call in a function and in the success function call the outer function again (recursively) passing in the next one in line until there are no more.

Comment: That would be another valid solution (and the way I used to solve it before promises). I would have chained `then` normally to solve this, but he wants to continue on fail which is unusual. Updated my own answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum you want:

```
testUrl = function (i) { 
    var d = $.Deferred();                  
    $.ajax({
        url: urls[i].url,
        dataType: "json"
    }).always(function(){
       d.resolve();
    });
    return d.promise();
};
```

Comment: @roryok: Based on your comment, this is the minimum you want to avoid the issues. Not quite an "anti-pattern".